# app config connection path

Tags: c#, ms-access, app-config

[image] my program work good when the path of database known
but when i make setup project change path of database to program path

but when i run my program show this message[image]

app.config code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ABB.Properties.Settings.ABBagain_CopyConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ABB_againCopy-Copy.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ABB.Properties.Settings.ABBagain_CopyConnectionString1"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ABB_againCopy-Copy.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ABB.Properties.Settings.ABBagain_CopyConnectionString2"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Users\Es\Desktop\ABB amr\ABBagain-Copy.accdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ABB.Properties.Settings.ABB_againCopy_CopyConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Users\Es\Desktop\final project\ABB_againCopy-Copy.accdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ABB.Properties.Settings.ABB_againCopy_CopyConnectionString1"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Users\AMR\Desktop\final project - Copy (2)\ABB_againCopy-Copy.accdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="ABB.Properties.Settings.ABB_againCopy_CopyConnectionString2"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ABB_againCopy-Copy.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

and connection string:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABB_againCopy-Copy"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABB_againCopy-Copy"] is wrong... you have no connection string NAMED ABB_againCopy-Copy use a name you have declared such as ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABB.Properties.Settings.ABBagain_CopyConnectionString"]

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection string with the name `ABB_againCopy-Copy`. That's why you get this error message.

Also, your connection strings contain a lot of fluff, that makes it hard to get the right one.

This:

```
ABB.Properties.Settings.ABB_againCopy_CopyConnectionString1
```

Could / should be:

```
ABB_againCopy-Copy
```

Comment: Did you try copy/pasting the connection string name from the one to the other?

Comment: this  app.config cod after correction <add name="ABB.Properties.Settings.ABBagain_CopyConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ABB_againCopy-Copy.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />

Comment: and connection string be string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABB.Properties.Settings.ABBagain_CopyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

Comment: Are you running this in the same project as the one where the app.config is?

Comment: c# code   oreach (DataRow r in dscontects.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                DataRow dr = _ABB_againCopy_CopyDataSet2.Table_History.NewRow();
                dr[0] = r[0];
                dr[1] = r[1];
                dr[2] = r[2];
                dr[3] = r[3];
                dr[4] = r[4];
                dr[5] = r[5];
                dr[6] = r[6];
                // dr[7] = r[7];
                _ABB_againCopy_CopyDataSet2.Table_History.Rows.Add(dr);

            }

            table_HistoryTableAdapter.Update(_ABB_againCopy_CopyDataSet2);

Comment: Connection string seems okay now. Sure it is the same error message on the same line?

Comment: Error message program cannot know data base path

Comment: The first window says it cannot find the file path. Is it correct?